# fast reference in Microsoft Word with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, reference

I have written two modules in the MS Word that can boost the speed of creat hyperlink for two words that they reference to each other:

[image]

This is useful specially when we want to reference many words. But my modules have a drawback. When I have many words, some of them may be repetitious. In the other words I have referenced the two words "book" in page1 and"boy"in page2  and now I want to reference the words "book"in page10 and "paper"in page20. With my modules this is impossible because book and book have one bookmark.   Is there a way two solve this problem? or does someone have an idea?

These are my modules:

```
        Public N1 As String 
         Public N2 As String 
        Public Name2 As String 
        Public R2 As Range 
    Sub Macro1()
        N2 = Selection.Text
        Set R2 = Selection.Range
        Name2 = Trim(N2)
        N2 = Name2
        Name2 = Name2 & "a"
        With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
            .Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:=Name2
            .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
            .ShowHidden = False
        End With
        With Selection.Range
            Selection.Font.Color = 16724787
            Selection.Font.UnderlineColor = wdColorAutomatic
            Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
        End With 
        End Sub
    
    Sub Macro2()
        N1 = Selection.Text
        Dim Name1 As String
        Name1 = Trim(N1)
        N1 = Name1
        Name1 = Name1 & "b"
        With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
            .Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:=Name1
            .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
            .ShowHidden = False
        End With
        With Selection.Range
            Selection.Font.Color = 16724787
            Selection.Font.UnderlineColor = wdColorAutomatic
            Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
        End With
        ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:="", _
            SubAddress:=Name2, ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=N1
        ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=R2, Address:="", _
            SubAddress:=Name1, ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=N2 
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary to manage boomarknames.  The following function will return the bookmarkname postfixed with a number.  The dictionary is local to the function but is easily declared at the module level if so required.

The "_" in the returned name makes it easy to retrieve the stem name by splitting at the "_".

```
Public Function GetBookMarkName(byref ipName as string) as String

    Static mBookmarks as Scripting.Dictionary
    If mBookmarks is nothing then 
        Set mBookmarks = new scripting.dicitonary
    end if

    if mBookmarks.Exists(ipName) then
       mBookmarks.Item(ipName) = mBookmarks.Item(ipName)+1
    else
       mBookmarks.Add myName,1
    end if
    
     GetBookmarkName = ipName & "_" & cstr(mBookmarks.Item(ipName))

end function
```

Comment: Thank you. I am checking it. I am learning to "how to create objects". Because
 if I write   dim abc as string , abc =getbookmarkname("xyxy") and run it, there is an error:User-defined type not defined

Comment: You need to add a reference to the microsoft.Scripting runtime.  In the IDE go Tools.References scroll down until you find the runtime library then make sure that the box at the LHS is ticked.  Alternatively you could create a late bound object by using CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") instead of 'New Scripting.Dictionary'